# Sort items in a nested hash by their key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested hash with unsorted keys:

```rb
given =  {
  "lorem" => {
     :AA => "foo",
     :GR => "foo",
     :BB => "foo"
  },
  "ipsum" => {
    :ZZ => "foo",
    :GR => "foo",
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a hash with sorted keys:

```rb
goal =  {
  "ipsum" => {
    :GR => "foo",
    :ZZ => "foo"
  },
  "lorem" => {
     :AA => "foo",
     :BB => "foo",
     :GR => "foo"
  }
}
```

I have experimented with .each method and sort_by

```rb
given.each { |topic| topic[:key].sort_by { |k, v| k } }
```

But I'm getting an error message: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: I noticed with gem pry the output is already sorted. But in IRB it's not.

Comment: This is a general question, but, why do you need to sort the keys in a hash?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I'm trying to iterate over the hash elements to build an html table. so the order of the elements is quite important to get the correct <td>.

Comment: I know that Ruby keeps the order in which the data was added. But I would still argue that, in theory, a hash is an unordered data structure. If you depend on your data being stored in a specific order you might want to consider another data structure, a nested array for example.

Comment: yes you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
given_hash =  {"lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :GR=>"foo", :BB=>"foo"}, "ipsum"=>{:ZZ=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}}
```

Get keys

```
given_hash.keys
=> ["lorem", "ipsum"]
```

New sorted hash

```
new_hash = {}
given_hash.keys.sort.each do |sorted_key|
  new_hash[sorted_key] = given[sorted_key]
end

 => {"ipsum"=>{:ZZ=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}, "lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :GR=>"foo", :BB=>"foo"}}
```

There can be a better way to do this.

Comment: hmm, with this implementation I'm getting just an array with keys only from first level.

Comment: @EmilyChoi Sorry but I didn't get you, and the given code sample in the answer just copies and paste from the console, which I did practically. can you please cross-check it, or maybe I'm not getting your question. The output I got is exactly the same which you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: hmm, the output I get with your implementation: => ["ipsum", "lorem"]

Comment: @EmilyChoi You haven't look at code `New sorted hash` below this :D, that's the answer which you are looking for,

Comment: ok, I did execute: given_hash =  {"lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :GR=>"foo", :BB=>"foo"}, "ipsum"=>{:ZZ=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}} ; new_hash = {} ;given_hash.keys.sort.each do |sorted_key|
  new_hash[sorted_key] = given[sorted_key]
end
# => ["ipsum", "lorem"]

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I'd love to select your answer as solution because it is very readable and easy to understand but the result is not what I expect and I don't have time to figure out why since Sebastian provided me a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilyChoi After running all code on your console just type `new_hash` you will able to see the result. as over each iteration sorted hash is being passed to `new_hash`. Thanks,

Comment: oh crap, my mistake! I apologize, your code is working perfectly fine!

Comment: @EmilyChoi Glad to know that :) by the way, let me know for any other guidance.

Comment: Emily, this answer is incorrect, in that the inner hashes are not reconstructed with the keys sorted, as required by your question and as mentioned by you in comments. Why would you select an answer that is incorrect over one that is correct (@Sebastian's)? Not only is Sebastian's answer correct but it leaves little or no room for improvement.

Comment: You said "The output I got is exactly the same which you have mentioned in the question." That's incorrect. You have reconstructed `given` with its two keys sorted, but you have not reconstructed the inner hashes with their keys sorted, as required by the question. For example, you obtain `new_hash["ipsum"] #=>{:ZZ=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}`, whereas the desired value for that is `{:GR=>"foo", :ZZ=>"foo"}`. I have for that reason downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group_by`, and `transform_values` to transform the values inside each hash, also using `sort_by` plus `to_h`:

```
given.transform_values { |value| value.sort.to_h }.sort.to_h

# {"ipsum"=>{:GR=>"foo", :ZZ=>"foo"}, "lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :BB=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}}
```

You're getting an error because when iterating over a hash, you have to local variables within the block scope to use, the key and its value, you're assigning only one (topic) and trying to get its key, which would be trying to access a key in:

```
["lorem", {:AA=>"foo", :GR=>"foo", :BB=>"foo"}]
```

Which isn't possible as is an array. You can update your code to:

```
given.each do |topic, value|
  ...
end
```

But anyway you'll need a way to store the changes or updated and sorted version of that topic values.

Comment: I believe the reference to `group_by` is a remnant.

Comment: Emily note that `given.transform_values {|value| value.sort }} #=> {"lorem"=>[[:AA, "foo"], [:BB, "foo"], [:GR, "foo"]], "ipsum"=>[[:GR, "foo"], [:ZZ, "foo"]]}`. Therefore, `h = given.transform_values {|value| value.sort.to_h } #=> {"lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :BB=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}, "ipsum"=>{:GR=>"foo", :ZZ=>"foo"}}`. Then `a = h.sort #=> [["ipsum", {:GR=>"foo", :ZZ=>"foo"}], ["lorem", {:AA=>"foo", :BB=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}]]` and lastly, `a.to_h #=> {"ipsum"=>{:GR=>"foo", :ZZ=>"foo"}, "lorem"=>{:AA=>"foo", :BB=>"foo", :GR=>"foo"}}`.